# Title of tabs appear on the right side of vertical accordion

Tags: html, image, css, jquery-ui-accordion

**What's going on?**:  The accordion is working properly, but the tabs show up on the right side of the accordion.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion .title").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".accordion .details").slideToggle(500)
    }).next().hide();
});
```

---

**CSS**:  **[Hoverbox](http://sonspring.com/journal/hoverbox-image-gallery)**

```
.hoverbox
{
    cursor: default;
    list-style: none;
} .hoverbox a {
    padding-top: 5px;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
} .hoverbox a .preview {
    display: none;
} .hoverbox a:hover .preview {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -33px;
    left: -45px;
    z-index: 1;
} .hoverbox img {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 125px;
} .hoverbox li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
} .hoverbox .preview {
    border-color: #000;
    height: 300px;
} .gallery {
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

**HTML**:  A sample for one image.

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="title"><h2></h2></div>
    <ul class="details">
    <div class="gallery">
    <ul class="hoverbox">
        <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="pictures/1.jpg" class="thumbnail"/>
            <img src="pictures/1.jpg" class="preview"/></br>
            Compass
        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

First, let's start off with a just loaded accordion.

[image: Accordion]

After I click "Glass Windows", this is what happens.

[image]

**What I have done**:  For the past four or five days I have been spending many hours relocating `<div>` tags, making sure my code is correct and dabbling with the CSS (specifically making sure the text wasn't aligned oddly or there was something goofy about how the images were displayed).  Not very specific, I know.  I apologize for the not so short and concise question.

---

## **Update**

I attempted to use Dexter's suggestion, but I still keep having issues with the text alignment.

After clicking on Section 1...

[image]

And Section 2...

[image]

As stated before, each section should be underneath one another.  The **Videos** section is separate from the accordion and **Home** is a part of the navigation list at the bottom of the page (serves as the footer).

I've come to understand that this may be an issue with my CSS for everything else not accordion related.  Since I have no idea what's the problem, I will just upload the entire CSS (which is about the same length as the accordion CSS)... if of course, that is 'okay'.

Comment: can you share link to ur website

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, if I may ask?

Comment: @DexterHuinda Although the accordion has not yet been styled completely, I would like a [simple accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion).  To be more specific, I want the text to be underneath each gallery (Lampshades would be under the last four images in Glass Windows).  While we're on the subject, I have not been able to figure out how to have just one tab opened at once; refer to the link provided for the simple accordion.

Comment: @SVS I am sorry, the site is still in development and has not been uploaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, is this what you're trying to achieve?

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GRATx/

EDIT:

Code in fiddle [updated with hoverbox functionality]: http://jsfiddle.net/GRATx/1/

Comment: The `.hoverbox` class allows the user to hover over an image to enlarge it.  I think this may have something to do with the incorrect formatting.  [Hoverbox](http://host.sonspring.com/hoverbox/).  Prior to adding this feature, I had the equivalent of your jsfiddle.

Comment: @MikeDtrick See this/my answer above. Updated fiddle here, showing hoverbox integrated with accordion: http://jsfiddle.net/GRATx/1/

Comment: Okay, I understand.  The issue isn't with the text CSS but with the accordion CSS.  I'll use the function that you used instead.  One more dumb question, can I style the accordion using this method?  I'd imagine the best course of action would be to use the [CSS used for the default accordion](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) and go from there.

Comment: @MikeDtrick yes use the default css, and then expand from there.

Comment: I just now set up my markup and script just like your jsfiddle and the accordion won't work at all... not to mention my accordion still looks like the second image in my question except all tabs are opened. I noticed you that you don't have any CSS in your fiddle. How did you get your accordion styled in that manner?  Please take a look at the Update section in my question as well.

Comment: By the way, the Hoverbox works just fine.  There are still issues with text alignment.

Comment: Completely disregard my last couple of comments, the accordion works great!  Thank you for the help.  +1