# Accordion animation broken upon setting height to auto!important

Tags: jquery, css, animation, height, accordion

**What's going on?**:  The animation for my jQuery accordion is broken.  It shows the previously opened tab after clicking on the next tab for a short period of time before closing the previous tab.  The animation doesn't slide either.

**CSS**:  Found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9515573/1118431)

```
/* The following was added into accordion.css */
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content { height: auto!important; }
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#accordion").accordion({ 
        active: false,
        fillSpace: false
    });

    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", false);
    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "fillspace", false);
});
```

---

**What I have tried**:  I have fiddled around with the values of `fillSpace` and `height`.  In accordion.css, I tried `overflow: visible!important;` but the formatting was really messed up.

**What I would like to happen**:  Clean animation with the height of each section depending upon the amount of content in each `<div>` (AKA what I had for the CSS above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel kind of silly now, but simply setting `autoHeight` to false takes away the unnecessary space underneath sections with less content.  The animation is also smooth.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#accordion").accordion({ 
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false, // ADDED
        collapsible: true
    });

    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", false);
    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "autoHeight", false); // ADDED
    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "collapsible", false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken you are using a plugin? And at least for me that is a problem (i hate them because of unexpected behavior). So a while ago I created my own accordion.
And you can check working example [**HERE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/A7f7J/)
Hope it helps you!

Here's my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.wrapper ul li ul:first').addClass('active');
   $('.wrapper ul li ul').hide();
   $('a.home,a.about,a.service,a.contact').click(function()     {
   if($('a.home,a.about,a.service,a.contact').next('ul').hasClass('active')) {
   $('.active').stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).next('ul').addClass('active');
   $('.active:not(:animated)').stop().slideDown('slow');
   }
   });
   });
```

Comment: I do agree that plugins have weird and unexpected behaviors.  I've been dabbling with the code for a while now and I can't seem to get my accordion to work.  This relates to my previous question about [text formatting issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171296/title-of-tabs-appear-on-the-right-side-of-vertical-accordion).  I updated my jQuery function, HTML and CSS; no luck.  Thank you for your help :)